# hibernate fail mapping two tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, hibernate-mapping, jboss-weld

I'd like to understand how it is possible:
Until I was working with one table everything worked fine,
when I have mapped another table it fails as shown below:

Glassfish start

```
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : hibernate_centrale.hbm.xml //first table
INFO: Mapping class: com.italtel.patchfinder.objects.centrale -> centrale
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : hibernate_impianti.hbm.xml //second table
INFO: Mapping class: com.italtel.patchfinder.objects.Impianto -> impianti
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null


INFO: schema update complete
INFO: Hibernate: select centrale0_.id as id0_, centrale0_.name as name0_, centrale0_.impianto as impianto0_, centrale0_.servizio as servizio0_ from centrale centrale0_ group by centrale0_.name
INFO: Hibernate: select centrale0_.id as id0_, centrale0_.name as name0_, centrale0_.impianto as impianto0_, centrale0_.servizio as servizio0_ from centrale centrale0_ where centrale0_.name='ANCONA' order by centrale0_.name asc

//Error
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: impianti is not mapped [from impianti where impianto='SD' order by modulo asc]
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:181)
...
```

config

table1

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD
3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.italtel.patchfinder.objects.Impianto" table="impianti">
        <id column="id" name="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="impianto"/>
        <property name="modulo"/>
    </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

table2

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.italtel.patchfinder.objects.centrale" table="centrale">
        <id column="id" name="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="impianto"/>
        <property name="servizio"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

connection stuff
...

```
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate_centrale.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate_impianti.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`

```
    public List<centrale> loadAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session.createQuery("from centrale group by name").list();
    }

    public List<centrale> loadImplants(String centrale) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session.createQuery("from centrale where name='" + centrale + "' order by name asc").list();
    }

    public List<Impianto> loadModules(String implant) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session.createQuery("from impianti where impianto='" + implant + "' order by modulo asc").list();
    }
}
```

Do you have some advice?

Comment: Could you fix the code so it's readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your mapping, your class name is Impianto, so your query should be "from Impianto..." not "from impianti..." - select from the class name, not the table name.

Comment: Was just going to post this. Also, for consistency, it would be good to capitalize your class names.